# What are the redis commands to disable for a normal application?

Tags: redis, acl, stackexchange.redis, ioredis, bull

We have a lot of services that use redis, and we are securing our new sharded cluster redis by creating a specific user for each service. What are the redis commands to disable for each user to secure our cluster? Our services have a normal usage of redis (read and write keys, pub/sub channels, some healthchecks, etc.), no one needs admin or dangerous commands. Is the following ACL sufficient to secure our redis?

```
user foo reset on>password resetkeys ~{bar:baz}:baz:* resetchannels ${bar:baz}:baz:* +@all -@admin -@dangerous
```

The aim is to basically secure our cluster, as do not allow a user to modify keys/channels of another, or do not allow a user to perform cluster/instance action, administration tasks, etc. Finally, all our services use https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis and https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull (with the connector https://github.com/luin/ioredis) clients.

Comment: I find this [Redis Security](https://university.redis.com/courses/ru330/) course much helpful than other resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the followings:

- Firstly: here is a specific list of ACL commands published by Redis:
  https://redis.io/commands/acl-cat/ (To be blocked)
- Secondly: You can restrict the access of the Redis users to a specific prefix
- Lastly: You can rename some of your commands using: rename-command in redis.conf file